# I'm seeing strange names in my list of docker containers, is someone having fun at docker or is that from hackers?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run a docker and it fails for various reasons. As I check my list of dockers (`docker ps -a`), I see those names:

```
pedantic_gauss
recursing_feynman
adoring_brattain
suspicious_tesla
gallant_gates
competent_gates
elated_davinci
ecstatic_mahavira
focused_mirzakhani
```

I use `docker-compose` and I'm sure we do not have such names in our setup files. Is that just something docker people thought would be fun to do?! I searched on some of those names and could not really find anything useful, although it looks like these appear on many sites, somewhat sporadically.

Comment: Those are the default names Docker will set when you don't set one yourself.

Comment: @ThoriumBR Wow! Good to know, but why not just use docker1, docker2, etc. These just look scary/hacky!

Comment: Perhaps you have a strange definition of scary/hacky :)

Comment: The names aren't scary. It's an adjective plus a famous name: Gauss, Tesla, Gates, Einstein...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in comments this is part of Docker's innate functionality, and is designed to make it easier to work with containers.

The canonical identifier for a Docker container is a SHA-256 hash, which is not the most user friendly thing to type.

So if you don't specify a name (using `--name`) when you start a container Docker will assign one to you.

The names are a combination of an adjective and a scientist's name, and the source code for generation is [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/4f0d95fa6ee7f865597c03b9e63702cdcb0f7067/pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go).  There is only one combination that is blocked in the Docker source code which is ["boring_wozniak"](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/4f0d95fa6ee7f865597c03b9e63702cdcb0f7067/pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go#L637) because Steve Wozniak's not boring.

Comment: Wow! They use a `goto`...

Comment: @AlexisWilke `angry_djisktra` is allowed by the code

Comment: @stevesliva https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf ... :-)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I finally figure out how does the wield name come from. I find this innovation is not very enjoyable. Perhaps the combination of using 'image name' and a 'random string ID' would be more suitable for new developers.